# Растягивание фотографий

Tags: android, java

Здравствуйте, у меня загружается фотография с url и отображается на девайсе. Но я не могу понять почему она не растягивается на весь экран. Предположим у фотографии размеры 1920х509. На экране устройства она является тонкой линией по середине устройства, а сверху и снизу белый фон, который задан в  imageView.
Вот код:

```
 loadImageFromURL(url);

}

private void loadImageFromURL(String url) {
/*  options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.profile)
            .showImageForEmptyUrl(R.drawable.profile).cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc().build();*/

    imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
    imageLoader.init(ImageLoaderConfiguration.createDefault(this));
    imageLoader.displayImage(url, imgView, options,
            new ImageLoadingListener() {

                public void onLoadingComplete() {
                    pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

                }

                public void onLoadingFailed() {

                    pbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }

                public void onLoadingStarted() {
                    pbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

}
```

Код разметки :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".DetailActivity" >
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgdesc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

попробуйте выставить свойство ScaleType  у Image View в FitXY